# CSRF session timing in Perfex CRM

Tags: php, csrf, crm

There's this code in it:
`define('APP_CSRF_PROTECTION', true);`
I'm getting 419 errors and I wish to increase session time. So should I keep it and add something like this (**as an additional line below in app-config.php file:**
`define('APP_CSRF_EXPIRE',3660*24*30);`
And what exactly are those numbers? I mean minutes, hours, days?

I've read it somewhere, but couldn't find a legend with details about those values. And what are the default values?